# Does Paribus Ceteris mean anything in Latin? If so, what?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I understand what [Ceteris Paribus mean](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/how-to-translate-ceteris-paribus) and that's exactly why I chose my handle, Paribus Ceteris, to make a play on the "all else being equal" meaning.

Ignoring if it even works in English, the question is does it work grammatically in Latin?

If so what would it mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's valid Latin, and means the same thing as *ceteris paribus*.

Latin word order is quite flexible, and constructions like this (ablative absolute with a substantive and a predicate) work just fine in either order. Sometimes a different word order changes the emphasis, but in this case, both orders read basically the same to me. *Paribus ceteris* just stands out a bit because it's better-known in the other order.

Comment: Damn latin, destroyed my wordplay. :) thanks!

Comment: @ParibusCeteris Out of curiosity, what did you want it to mean?

Comment: Anything but the same :)

Comment: @ParibusCeteris I dunno, I feel like the fact that “all else [aside from the order] is the same” is rather fitting wordplay here.

Comment: @KRyan yeah! looking at it that way it may even make it stronger, everyting else *including the meaning* is equal - thanks!